# Mongodb query says "wrong number of arguements (2 for 1)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

My query is dead simple, not sure what is going on:

User.rb

```
def self.find_house_number(house_number)
  User.where("house_number = ?", house_number)
end
```

So calling it:

```
User.find_house_number("9998883333")
```

I get the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where says User.where(:house_number => house_number) is the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#where` takes a conditions hash, not a SQL-like string. You should do this instead:

```
User.where(:house_number => house_number)
```

Note that MongoDB has nothing to do with SQL, so you shouldn't assume that SQL fragments will work.

Comment: Also, this would probably be better implemented as a scope, so that it's chainable with other queries, like `scope :with_house_number, lambda{|house_number| where(:house_number => house_number)}`. Then you could do things like `User.with_house_number('123').where(:city => 'London')`

Comment: Scopes are somewhat deprecated. Class methods get you equivalently powerful constructs without needing to introduce a second syntax.

Comment: Ack. Of course - I don't know why I even suggested it, considering that I myself use class methods over scopes. Need moar caffines.

Comment: I don't see a single example on the mongoid where section that has:  .where(:field => your_field)   ?

Comment: It's the very first example. They're just using the Ruby 1.9 Hash syntax (`foo: 123` is the same as `:foo => 123`).

Comment: will this return an array or a single model?

Comment: It returns an array of all documents matching the conditions hash. If you want just one.